# How to call captured image in another activity{Don't need it to be displayed}

Tags: java, android

am writing a body measurement app. I have been able to create the camera and it stores the image. I want to use the captured image in another activity where i called the method 'bodyMeasurement'
I really need help in achieving this. Further corrections are also welcomed. Thanks

Here is my Camera Activity;

```
CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice=null;
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        btnCapture = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);


       /* Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        if (!report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You need to grant all permission to use this app features", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {

                    }
                })
                .check();*/

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if(characteristics != null)
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = 4608;
            int height = 3456;
            if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0)
            {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //Check orientation base on device
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ ".CnatraSamp"+".jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try{
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if(image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try{
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    }finally {
                        if(outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };



            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   finish();

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BlankActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            };

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try{
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert  texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try{
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[1];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }

    };




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try{
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread= null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
```

the activity i need the image;

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blank);

        height = findViewById(R.id.height);
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        btnctn = findViewById(R.id.continuebtn);
        cmIn = findViewById(R.id.cmIn);

        height.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |
                InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL |
                InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);




        btnctn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (height.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){

                    Toast.makeText(BlankActivity.this,"Please input your height..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BlankActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting Your Measurement");
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait!");
                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent i = new Intent(BlankActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    },5000);

                }

                //place measurement object
                bodyMeasurement();

            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BlankActivity.this.finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(BlankActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        cmIn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    num = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(height.getText()));
                    in = 0.3937 * num;
                    String r = String.valueOf(in);
                    height.setText(r);
                }else {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(height.getText()));
                    cm = num / 0.3937;
                    String r = String.valueOf(cm);
                    height.setText(r);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void bodyMeasurement() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can send file path in Intent extras to the activity where you want to get the image.
Here your file is:-    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ ".CnatraSamp"+".jpg");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can get the absolute path from the saved image and pass it through an intent to the Activity that it needs it.
To achieve this, you might want to convert your image file to a BitMap first, which will give you the actual path of the image (sometimes .getAbsolutePath() method returns a wrong file path, so it is a better solution to convert your image to a bitmap first).

This can be achieved:

```
String filePath = file.getPath();  
Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

Then to obtain the real path of the image you saved you need to 
1) Obtain the Uri of the created Bitmap:

```
public Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap imgBitmap) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), 
  imgBitmap, "Title", null);

  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

2) Fetch the real path from Uri:

```
public String getRealPath(Uri uri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,  null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

In your first activity you can pass the path of your image through an intent to the other activity, then fetch it and display it/etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PATH",path);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive the data you passed:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String path = intent.getStringExtra("PATH");
//convert the path to image/bitmap and display the image
```

You can also pass the entire Bitmap to the Activity you need it, but I strongly recommend that you don't, because it will use a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what would you recommend if that would use a lot of memory? @Giannis Brandt

Comment: @daring You can just pass the path of the file as shown above.This will tell you where the image is in your memory, and from there you can manipulate it the way you want.